# Ubuntu 12.04 changing permissions External Hard Drive from Terminal

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, recovery-mode

I am attempting to rescue files from a broken system via the root terminal of the recovery console.

I have a seagate 2TB external hard drive.  Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/sdb1 is the device boot
HPFS/NTFS/exFAT is the system
```

Everytime I try to copy files to the hard drive via:

```
sudo cp [file] /media/Expansion\ Drive
```

I get:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/Expansion Drive/[file]' : Read only file system
```

I have tried:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /media/Expansion\ Drive
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/Expansion\ Drive
```

and

```
sudo chmod a+rwx -R /media/Expansion\ Drive
```

and for each command, the output is:

```
chmod:  changing permissions of `/media/Expasion Drive': Read-only file system
```

So I'm at a loss.  I've tried searching for more help, but the majority of solutions that I have found involve using nautilus of some other GUI and I am unable to access those resources because I can only access from the recovery console root shell

Please help! The crash seemed spontaneous and I was unable to back up my current project... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also would like to mention that when I cd into the external hard drive's directory and ls, it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount your drive manually with write permission

```
mount -t FSTYPE -o uid=X,gid=Y,umask=022 /dev/sdbX /path/to/mount/point
```

For your uid and gid run the following command

```
id your_user_name
```

To find out the file-system type

```
sudo file -s /dev/sdbX
```